# Where Can I Look Up Azure ARM Template Parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to deploy Azure ARM Templates, but I do not what to put in parameters boxes. Is there a place where I can look up what each parameter do, what is the correct syntax, what parameters accept what symbols and how long should the passwords, salts be?
This is the template I'm trying to deploy https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/wordpress-mysql-replication/

I have problems with most parameters. For example:

website sku - what do I put here?

website worker size - what do I put here?

webdeploy secure authentication key - how many symbols should it have? Will it accept special symbols, like % or ;

vmSize - what is the correct sytax? Just A2? or vm_size_a2? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Convenient way to learn the ARM is to use [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) which can be bound to your subscription and you may see all of your resources in the needed form.

Here, if you go to the branch you want (in your case it is Web) you will find the documentation about parameters/etc -

```
 your subscription name => resourceGroups branch => resourceGroup name => providers => Microsoft.Web => sites => any site => documentation.
```

The process of using the RE in more details is described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye9eOYRK3jE)

Regarding your mentioned script, some of parameters looks as a custom names. Parameters are described [here in some capacity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/wordpress-mysql-replication/azuredeploy.json) in the script itself, and your exact parameters are:

**website sku** - basic/standard/premium. Plans are described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)

**website worker size** - it is one of the components that typically used for scalability. Described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-scale-a-web-app-in-an-app-service-environment/). They are actual for ASE, premium mode. I believe you should not need that if you are not going to use premium mode.

**webdeploy secure authentication key** - it is something Wordpress-related, sorry, not sure what it should be. Looks like it may be taken from the [official site generator](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/). And [that article](http://www.itexperience.net/2014/01/20/how-to-set-up-a-wordpress-website-in-your-windows-azure-account/) may be helpful (screenshots especially).

**vmSize** - Standard_D2 as described in the [script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/wordpress-mysql-replication/azuredeploy.json).

There is a lack of documentation for that script, and some parameters are not ARM-relevant.

Comment: Thank you, @alex-belotserkovskiy . This answers my question. Although, it would be nice to have a single document listing ARM templates syntax.

Comment: @TestMinute7 glad it helped - could you please mark the question answered? Regarding your request - it is clear that it is needed, but in some cases these extra parameters/arguments are not ARM-related, so it may bring the confusion. Resource Explorer is the way to go in most cases.